# Calculating $Spec(\mathbb{C}[x]/\langle x^2 \rangle)$

Tags: commutative-algebra

I am currently trying to calculate $S = Spec(\mathbb{C}[x]/\langle x^2 \rangle)$.

I'm pretty sure that $Spec(\mathbb{C}[x])$ is the set $\{x - \alpha : \alpha \in \mathbb{C} \} \cup \{0\}$ (ie - irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x]$), since these are all prime ideals.

My guess is that $S$ will be the set of irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x]/\langle x^2 \rangle$, which I think would be $\{x - \alpha : \alpha \in \mathbb{C} \} \cup  \{x^3 - \beta x^2 : \beta \in \mathbb{C}\}\cup \{0\}$.

Is this correct?  I feel like this shouldn't be right; like my thinking is too naive and misses out something quite subtle.

Also, what would be the "best" way for calculating $Spec(R)$, when $R$ is of this sort of form?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space $Spec \ \mathbf{C}[x]/(x^2)$ is a one point space: the prime ideals of $\mathbf{C}[x]/(x^2)$ correspond to those in $\mathbf{C}[x]$ containing $(x^2)$, and $(x)$ is the only prime ideal of $\mathbf{C}[x]$ that contains $(x^2)$. (So no, you are not correct.) Generally speaking, you probably know that if $\phi:A\rightarrow B$ is a surjective ring morphism, the induced map $\phi^\ast: Spec \ B\rightarrow Spec \ A$ is a closed injection, hence gives a homeomorphism of $Spec \ B$ onto the set of prime ideals containing the kernel of $\phi$.

Comment: So, in general, does this mean that $Spec(\mathbb{K}[x]/\langle f \rangle)$ corresponds to the prime ideals in $\mathbb{K}[x]$ containing $\langle f \rangle$ (for some field $\mathbb{K}$)? :-)

Comment: @user143137 yes exactly. what I say is much more general, and includes the case of any quotient. you might want to work out $ \ \mathbf{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)$ (Gaussian integers) after looking up what $Spec \ \mathbf{Z}[x]$ is.

Comment: @Laters Would a suitable $\phi$ be $\phi:\mathbb{C}[x]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x]/\langle x^2 \rangle$, where $\phi(a_0 + a_1x +...+a_nx^n) = a_0 + a_1x + \langle x^2 \rangle$ ?

Comment: @Jango in general the quotient (canonical) ring morphism $\phi:A\rightarrow A/\mathfrak{a}$, $x\mapsto x+\mathfrak{a}$ is surjective