# What is the spectrum of $\mathbb{Z}_{\langle 5 \rangle}$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm trying to describe the spectrum of this ring. I've figured that this is a local ring with maximal ideal generated by $\frac{5}{1}$, so I have that $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}_{\langle 5\rangle})=\{\langle5\rangle,\dots\}$. I'm not sure how to figure out the other elements of the spectrum... how do I go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primes of the localization $\mathbb{Z}_{(5)}$ correspond bijectively to primes of $\mathbb{Z}$ contained within $(5)$. (More generally, primes in $S^{-1} R$ correspond to primes of $R$ contained within $R \backslash S$.) The bijection sends an ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq S^{-1}R$ to its preimage $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ under the natural map $f : R \rightarrow S^{-1} R.$

So in particular the primes of $\mathbb{Z}_{(5)}$ are $(5)$ and $(0)$.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. In this case, do we have Spec$(\mathbb{Z}_{(4)}) = \{(2), (0)\}$, or Spec$(\mathbb{Z}_{(7)}) = \{(7), (0)\}$.

Comment: @IanBaker There is no such thing as $\mathbb Z_{(4)}$: the ideal $(4)$ is not prime, so you can't localise with respect to it. But you're right about ${\rm Spec}(\mathbb Z_{(7)})$. By the way, rings of the form $\mathbb Z_{(p)}$ with $p$ prime are examples of discrete valuation domains: they have a unique maximal ideal, which is also the only non-zero prime ideal.

Comment: By the original answer, can we generally say that for $A = \mathbb{K}[x]_{(f)}$, $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is the prime ideals of $\mathbb{K}[x]$ containing $(f)$? For example would $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x]_{(x)}) = \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x]_{(x^2)}) = \{(x)\}$?

Comment: @IanBaker As Kenny said, you localize at prime ideals. There is no $\mathbb{C}[x]_{(x^2)}$. Also, $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x]_{(x)})$ still contains $(0)$. I think what you mean may be $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x] / (x)) = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x] / (x^2)) = \{(x)\},$ which is true as sets.

Comment: Oh right, sorry. I meant the second thing - whats the reasoning behind that? And in terms of $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x]_{(x)})$, would it just be the set $\{(0), (x)\}$ then, for the reasons outlined above?

Comment: Oh, I saw a linked [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1127785/calculating-spec-mathbbcx-langle-x2-rangle?rq=1). This seems to clear it up, but going back to the localisations idea - is $(0)$ always contained in the spectrum of a localisation?

Comment: @IanBaker $(0)$ is prime if and only if the ring has no zero divisors. Localizing is a bit weird with zero divisors. If you stay away from that then $(0)$ will be in your spectrum as you say.